# DateTime string returns differently between .Net 2 & 4

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datetime, .net-4.0

I have the same date retrieval in my server side:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(seconds);
string time = dt;
```

on .Net 2 the date string returns as MM/DD/YYYY,
but in .Net 4 it returns as DD/MM/YYYY

My .Net 2 runs on server 2003 in Israel time zone,
My .Net 4 runs on server 2008 in Israel time zone
The time formatting on them is identical.

I know I can format the string as I want but I wonder if this issue is a known one.

Is there were any change between .Net2 & .Net4 or between Server 2003 to 2008?

Comment: Have you confirmed what the time formatting is on each server? The culture will set a default format for the culture, but that can be overridden - someone may have done that. It'll be a server setting.

Comment: Show the code where you are converting dt to a string.

Comment: If the 2003 server is a US English server version and the newer machine runs a Hebrew version of Windows, that'd afaict be the expected output.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth The time formatting on them is identical

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The time formatting on them is identical